# Gltf 404 Error : Can't Host on Server

Tags: http-status-code-404, aframe, gltf

I'm new to Gltf files and am trying to host a file exported using Kronos' Blender export. Seems to export my file fine but I am getting a 404 error when using A Frame to load it AND when I try to directly paste the path in a browser.

When I link to a CDN of an existing gltf ( say this avacado ) it functions fine and if I go to said path in a browser it downloads the gltf.

```
<a-asset-item id="house" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/9176d098/1.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf"></a-asset-item>
```

Yet once I download that Avacado.gltf and host it on my server ( or on other servers I have access to ) and go to the direct path, sure enough, there is a 404 error.

Is gltf not recognized or is there something specific i need to set up in order for this to work?

Comment: Try using the 'glb' export from the Blender glTF exporter.  `glb` is the binary form of glTF and typically includes embedded data and textures in a single file.

Comment: Yes - this seems to not throw a 404 error if I use aframe 0.7.0. Yet there's nothing appearing. I have altered scale, position etc. I have added blenders material of a simple lambert blue and have kept it unshaded as well. Here is the glb hosted through aframe's cdn:  Of note, I've tried to host it on aframes cdn:  https://ucarecdn.com/eb8f435c-b43c-4d62-9ffc-046bf4ca9fdf/

Comment: Other hosted glb : https://ucarecdn.com/d1c83e49-4b21-4d4b-b59d-c1e582374a13/  Blender v 2.77

Answer (score 1):

The gltf file has references to multiple other files (e.g. .bin file, textures)
The avocado seems to have a `.bin`, and multiple `.jpg`'s, which need to be together with the `.gltf` file.

Link to the [avocado](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF) <- Check out how many files are there in the catalogue.

Comment: When exporting using Blender's gltf 2.0 exporter, it creates a zipped bin and a gltf file. I upload both to my server...and I have tried relative linking to them and absolute linking to them. My server is also SSL. It just cannot find that file. Also of note, I know that the older version of AFrame doesnt support gltf 1.0 but I am linking to <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>. I have also tried exporting as 1.0 and using previous AFrame versions.

Comment: @pwhitt did You try Don McCurdy [Loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders) ?

Comment: Your avocado link is to the glTF 1.0 folder, and I believe A-Frame wants a glTF 2.0 file, you may want to update the link to the 2.0 folder.

Comment: @emackey thanks, it should work, as long as ALL files from the exporter are uploaded together

Comment: The avacado works when linking directly to the cdn using 0.6.0. The issue is creating my own object and exporting via Blender. There is a threejs error. Three.js:30146 GET https://blahblahpath/myhouse.gltf 404 (Not Found). ( using AFrame 0.7.0 )

Comment: did You try Don's loaders, it should help since he is doing a-frame's 3D model work. Try both loaders (1.0 and 2.0)

Comment: I'll check those out as soon as I don't get github's unicorn. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: Well I don't know if i'm getting closer or not but at least I don't get a 404. Now in both versions of AFrame ( 0.6.0 and 0.7.0 tested ) I get a Cannot read property 'length' of undefined which when opened points to zLength = vertices.length; I have the latest version of Blender's three js export ( to json ) and I am linking to Don McCurdy's latest addons:<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> I looked for an older 1.0 loader to no avail.

Comment: And by loading that cdn: https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.13.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js and using the same method to load ( gltf and not three js json ): <a-entity gltf-model="url(housev1.gltf)"></a-entity> still gives a 404 despite uploading both the gltf and the .bin file that is exported from blender.

Comment: @pwhitt i just tried it out, the blender exporter, and a-frame 0.7 are working as expected if You are hosting them on Your own server: http://gftruj.nazwa.pl/experiments/glTF/2/ . Are you sure you didn't mix any paths, or you copied all exported files ?